# JS Async and await to work in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, asynchronous

I have already gotten my project to work on with async/await in every other browser, but apparently its not compatible in IE.

```js
(async function () {
  try {
    await getLayers();
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}());
```

which calls my other function:

```js
async function getLayers() {  
try {
  $.when(
    await $.getJSON('http://' + ipAddress + '/api/Barriers/barrierGeoJSON', function (data) {
        createLayer(data[0].row_to_json, 'Barrier');
      }),
     await $.getJSON('http://' + ipAddress + '/api/DistPoints/distPointGeoJSON', function (data) {
        createLayer(data[0].row_to_json, 'Disturbance Points');
      })
  )}
  catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

I need help getting this code to run on IE. Is there some sort of polyfill or transpiler that I have to use? I would hate to have to rewrite everything when it already runs smoothly. This is currently running client-side and I could not figure out how to use [async--await](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async--await). Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: Use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)

Comment: Don't really see why you use `await` for the `$.getJSON` calls. They don't seem dependent on each other

Comment: @charlietfl theres 10 more getJSON calls, I just wanted to shorten the code.

Comment: simple enough to wrap them up into array of promises if you want to avoid a transpiler. Also if they don't depend on each other await will slow them down

Comment: @djfdev Thank you for this! This will help me a lot down the line. It gave me some good code back but I am still getting errors. It set me on the right track though.

Comment: @charlietfl how would I wrap them into an array of promises? Also another person wrote out this part of the function so I assumed he used awaits so that bigger data calls would not run at the same time slowing down the app.

Comment: It looks like you actually want to use `await $.when($.ajax(…), $.ajax(…))`. If you want to run them sequentially (with multiple `await`s), there's no need for `$.when`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ended up using [**babel**](http://babeljs.io/repl/) to convert this portion of my code to work with IE11. Also I had to import a polyfill so the regeneratorRuntime function will work.

**It became this which works across all browsers**:

```js
_asyncToGenerator( /*#__PURE__*/regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee() {
  return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function _callee$(_context) {
    while (1) {
      switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
        case 0:
          _context.prev = 0;
          _context.next = 3;
          return getLayers();

        case 3:
          _context.next = 8;
          break;

        case 5:
          _context.prev = 5;
          _context.t0 = _context['catch'](0);

          console.error(_context.t0);

        case 8:
        case 'end':
          return _context.stop();
      }
    }
  }, _callee, this, [[0, 5]]);
}))();
```

```js
'use strict';

var getLayers = function () {
  var _ref = _asyncToGenerator( /*#__PURE__*/regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee() {
    return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function _callee$(_context) {
      while (1) {
        switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
          case 0:
            _context.prev = 0;
            _context.t0 = $;
            _context.next = 4;
            return $.getJSON('http://' + ipAddress + '/api/Barriers/barrierGeoJSON', function (data) {
              createLayer(data[0].row_to_json, 'Barrier');
            });

          case 4:
            _context.t1 = _context.sent;
            _context.next = 7;
            return $.getJSON('http://' + ipAddress + '/api/DistPoints/distPointGeoJSON', function (data) {
              createLayer(data[0].row_to_json, 'Disturbance Points');
            });

          case 7:
            _context.t2 = _context.sent;

            _context.t0.when.call(_context.t0, _context.t1, _context.t2);

            _context.next = 14;
            break;

          case 11:
            _context.prev = 11;
            _context.t3 = _context['catch'](0);

            console.error(_context.t3);

          case 14:
          case 'end':
            return _context.stop();
        }
      }
    }, _callee, this, [[0, 11]]);
  }));

  return function getLayers() {
    return _ref.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}();

function _asyncToGenerator(fn) { return function () { var gen = fn.apply(this, arguments); return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { function step(key, arg) { try { var info = gen[key](arg); var value = info.value; } catch (error) { reject(error); return; } if (info.done) { resolve(value); } else { return Promise.resolve(value).then(function (value) { step("next", value); }, function (err) { step("throw", err); }); } } return step("next"); }); }; }

;
```

Comment: Interesting subject, but I find your answer not clear, as we can't find your original code in it (including the await keyword). Maybe you should develop the use of Babel too, to make it more straight-forward.

Comment: @Bob The reason that the `await` keyword is not in the answer, is that IE apparently does not support `async-await`. So using babel to convert my code to an IE compatible version, it removed the asyncs and awaits.

Comment: for anyone who is looking for the regeneratorRuntime  error
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/babel-polyfill