# Open multiple tabs using JavaScript on Bing for Mobile

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, bing

I know how to open Multiple Tabs using JavaScript but my solution does not seem not to work on "Bing for mobile".

I'm trying to achieve the following.

- Whenever a user clicks on the Call Now button, a call to specified number should be made and the page should redirect to some other page.

For this, the sample code I used is,

```html
<a id="makeCall" onclick="callNRedirect()">  <!-- Target blank, if you want to open in new tab -->

   <img alt="Call icon" src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/14e16f_9f3a8d8153914af3b9ee7c1bb7218506~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_354,h_212,al_c,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/14e16f_9f3a8d8153914af3b9ee7c1bb7218506~mv2.png" style="width: 170px;" />

</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
 
   let callNRedirect = function(){
       makeCall().then(function() {
           window.top.location.href = 'http://www.business-insurance-now.com/call2';
       });
  
   }

   async function makeCall() {
       window.open("tel:989898", “_blank”);
   }
</script>
```

The thing is, it is working fine on Webkit based browsers, but Bing for mobile and Microsoft Edge are not working as expected.

Live link for the demo: https://codestroke.blogspot.com/2018/10/samples-samples-everywhere.html

The Bing app won't open the dial app.
The Edge app won't redirect to the page.

Update: Looks like the Edge was blocking the redirection, so it is kinda solved. Not sure of bing though!

Comment: what is the version of mobile and type, plus what is your browser full version

Comment: I've just downloaded Bing from Andriod app store. It's the latest. Not sure of exact versioning info.

Comment: please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684102/js-async-and-await-to-work-in-internet-explorer i tried but could not make it work yet

Comment: Microsoft Edge on Android version: 42.5.3

Comment: Can I use promises instead?

Comment: Why do you need async and call back cant you just have simple function like the `function callNRedirect() {
       window.open("tel:989898", "_blank" );
   }` what are you trying to do with your code

Comment: Bcoz I want to redirect to two pages at once. One for phone call and other for another page

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple example to open 2 links using HREF.

```html
<a href="http://Microsoft.com" onclick="window.open('http://Bing.com');
return true;">multiopen</a>
```

If you want to open more then 2 links then you can try to refer example below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<script>
function demo()
 {
    
    window.open('http://yahoo.com');
    window.open('http://bing.com');
    window.open('http://microsoft.com');
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="#" onclick="demo()">multiopen</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This solution works fine on WebKit based browsers but I'm trying to get it working on Bing for mobile. I don't know, maybe it has some kind of settings that do not allow multiple tabs to open.