# _ context.sent undefined when using async function, only in IE11

Tags: javascript, async-await, internet-explorer-11, babeljs, polyfills

I'm having some difficulty with using async funtionality in IE. Basically my implementation works fine in modern browsers but I hit an error in IE11. My original code is as follows.

```
    const instance = this;
    var success;
    try {
        success = await aSpecificLoader(parameters);
        const thisObject= success.ref;
        thisObject.on('loadstart', () => {
            instance.callAnotherFunction(thisObject);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("failed to load desired object", error);
    }
},
```

I'm using babel 7.3.4 with and including the libraries regenerator-runtime.js and es6-promise-auto.js  my transpiled code is as follows:

```
var _this = this;

return _asyncToGenerator(
/*#__PURE__*/
regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee() {
    var instance, success, thisObject;
    return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function _callee$(_context) {
    while (1) {
        switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
        case 0:
            instance = _this;
            _context.prev = 1;
            _context.next = 4;
            return aSpecificLoader(parameters);

        case 4:
            success = _context.sent;
            thisObject = success.ref;
            thisObject.on('loadstart', function () {
            instance.callAnotherFunction(thisObject);
            });
            _context.next = 12;
            break;

        case 9:
            _context.prev = 9;
            _context.t0 = _context["catch"](1);
            console.error("failed to load desired object", _context.t0);

        case 12:
        case "end":
            return _context.stop();
        }
    }
    }, _callee, null, [[1, 9]]);
}))();
},
```

I've seen some similar issues before but in this particular case _context (in case 4) is defined but _context.sent is not.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jonny

Comment: `async` functions are not supported in IE- https://caniuse.com/#search=async%20functions

Comment: Try to set debugger to check the `_context` object, perhaps it is a null object. Besides, please refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684102/js-async-and-await-to-work-in-internet-explorer) to convert the script.