# CrossStorageClient could not connect in IE 11

Tags: localhost, ssl-certificate, local-storage, virtual-machine, cross-domain

I'm debugging a website on my machine with Windows and Windows Subsystem for Linux.

I use [cross-storage](https://github.com/zendesk/cross-storage) in my website. I can launch the website `https://localhost:3000/sign` under Chrome, whereas in IE it raises an error `CrossStorageClient could not connect`, which blocks the page.

No error in Chrome:
[image]

`CrossStorageClient could not connect` in IE
[image]

In the client side, it seems that it is `new CrossStorageClient(...)` that raises the error.

```
const storage = new CrossStorageClient(`https://localhost:3000/htmls/hub.html`, {}); 

export async function getSignToken() {
  await storage.onConnect();
```

If I open `https://localhost:3000/htmls/hub.html` in IE in a tab, it shows a problem of `security certificate`, I could click on `Go on to the webpage (not recommended)` to continue. (The `CrossStorageClient could not connect` error of the client side is still raised regardless of this).
[image]

Here is `hub.html` on the server side:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <title>Production Cross Storage Hub</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/hub.js"></script>
  <script>
    CrossStorageHub.init([
        {origin: /:\/\/localhost(:[0-9]*)?$/, allow: ['get', 'set', 'del']},
        {origin: /\.10studio.tech$/, allow: ['get', 'set', 'del']},
        {origin: /:\/\/(www\.)?10studio.tech$/, allow: ['get', 'set', 'del']}
    ]);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So, does anyone know how to fix this `CrossStorageClient could not connect` error?

Is there any other alternative than CrossStorageClient?

Comment: Do you have async/await pollyfil for IE or any other tool for it, eg Babel..? IE is not supporting this features: https://caniuse.com/#search=async

Comment: I forgot to mention that this link can be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684102/js-async-and-await-to-work-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score 1):

I think that has to do with timeout config. Change it to 30000 and test again (if it doesn't work, try increase the number)

```
const storage = new CrossStorageClient(`https://localhost:3000/htmls/hub.html`, {timeout: 30000});
```

Comment: It's mentioned at link https://github.com/zendesk/cross-storage/issues/50