# how to add async/await support to cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, asynchronous, async-await

Im using cordova last version to develop mobile app, but when I try to use async function I get this error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function`

it seems that the webView that cordova runs at, is not supporting async/await. I tried to use babel but I couldn't figure out what version is the solution and how should I do that.

dose anybody has any solution for this?

p.s: I don't want to use pormisifier, I need exactly async and await

tnx

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a bunch of libraries that can polyfill async await. A quick google returned this project https://github.com/DanielHerr/Async-Await , or this site [here](https://polyfill.io/v3/url-builder/) there could be many others.

You could also check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684102/js-async-and-await-to-work-in-internet-explorer)